# Django order_by randomizes queryset twice?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to randomize a query set for a program i'm working on.

This is what's is in my views.py

```
full_quiz = Quiz.objects.get(name=quiz_name).questions.all()
form = TheForm(full_quiz)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = QuestionForm(request.GET, full_quiz)
```

This is what is in my forms.py

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, questions, *args, **kwargs):
    super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for i in range(len(questions)): 
        if questions[i].answer.count() < 2:
            self.fields["field_name %d" % i] = forms.CharField(label=questions[i], required=False)
```

From my testing, it appears like the query set is getting randomized with the second form variable. Any fix for this?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you adding request.GET data to your form after checking the method if it is "POST"?

Comment: When I made it request.POST for my form I got this error: MultiValueDictKeyError.

Comment: Please provide more details on what you are trying to achieve and the code for your forms.

Comment: I am trying to make a quiz and then the user can submit their answers. But now I am trying to make it so the quiz's questions are shuffled instead of being put in the same order. Not sure if this is right but I process the score of the quiz inside the view.py.

Comment: Just for clarification: You are trying to display a page where the user sees a formset with all the questions for a specific quiz in some random order? And after answering the questions and the formset is submitted the answers will be saved?

Comment: The answers are not saved, just processed in views.py to get the number of correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random order queryset as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/):

```
full_quiz = Quiz.objects.get(name=quiz_name).questions.order_by('?')
```

You have not posted the code of your forms but I expect QuestionForm is a ModelFormSet. You can change the queryset of a ModelFormSet by setting the queryset arg (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset)):

```
form = QuestionForm(queryset=fullquiz)
```

Suppose you have a model structure like this

```
class Quiz(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField('Quizname', max_length=200)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField('Question')

class Answer(models.Model):

    reply = models.CharField('Answer', max_length=100)

class Question(models.Model):

    the_question = models.CharField('Question', max_length=100)
    answers = models.ManyToManyField('Answer', related_name='answers')
    correct_answer = models.ForeignKey('Answer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def is_correct(self, given_answer):
        return given_answer == self.correct_answer
```

you could create a form structure with a `ModelForm` and a `ModelFormSet`:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    myanswers = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Answer.objects.all(), widget=forms.RadioSelect, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('the_question', 'myanswers')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myanswers'].queryset = self.instance.answers.all()


QuestionFormSet = modelformset_factory(Question, form=QuestionForm, extra=0)
```

And use it in a view:

```
def myview(request, quiz_name):

  if request.method == 'POST':
      formset = QuestionForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          allanswers = [f['id'].is_correct(f['myanswers']) for f in formset.cleaned_data]
          print('Number of correct answers:', sum(allanswers))

  fullquiz = Quiz.objects.get(name=quiz_name).questions.order_by('?')
  formset = QuestionForm(queryset=fullquiz)
  return render(request, 'yourtemplate.html', {'formset': formset })
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added how I set up my forms.py.

Comment: @user8802333 Any reason why you are not using a ModelFormSet for your QuestionForm?

Comment: The way I used was the only one I found on how to collect the cleaned data (using field_name #). I couldn't figure out how to do this with ModelFormSet.

Comment: @user8802333 See my suggestion in the edited answer

Comment: Thank for the answer. Unfortunately, didn't seem to work on my end.